# Privileged users reviews

Tags: discussion, review

I am suspecting that (some) of my answers are being reviewed by high privileged users, like I review first answers for example.

If my suspicion is right, *and as I feel part of this community*, I ask myself if I don't have the right to know if I'm being reviewed in my interactions, and have some feedback if necessary.

Comment: You do have this right, but what exactly is your question? Is it whether there’s a secret review queue only “privileged users” (please define that) can access? Or is it whether you personally are monitored somehow?

Comment: @dessert "Or is it whether you personally are monitored somehow?" Oh no, no, please. By priviliged users I mean those who have enough reputation to gain some kind of queue review, that other users don't know about. What you call "secret", I would call it "information that users can't access without privilege"

Comment: I'm not paranoid :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> have the right to know if I'm being reviewed

Maybe... I mean, we're all being monitored in the sense that everything we do here is seen by other users. On top of that, the lowest rep users have most of their posts fed into review queues, you will have your edits scrutinised before being approved until you hit 2k rep. And anybody can flag something  of yours for a moderator to intervene, whatever your reputation.

But what's the value is in *telling* everybody that something is is going to be reviewed though? That's just noise.

> and have some feedback if necessary

You absolutely **would** have some feedback in those cases. The important part there is "if necessary".

The actions that people take in review are similar  to normal ones. They can vote (for and again), they can reject edits, they can improve them, they can comment (on first posts, reopen queue). With each of those you can infer that something wasn't perfect.

We're all just trying to get along, help a few Ubuntu users and keep the site clean for people in the future. If you want specific feedback about something, ask for it. In chat, here on Meta. We'll do our best to help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My suspicion was wrong then, at least in the sense that there's a special queue.